# Why doesn't splunk convert log in json format to json

Tags: json, amazon-cloudwatch, splunk

I set up a cluster on AWS EKS and use cloudwatch to send its stdout logs to a Splunk service. I want to do complex search on the `log` and draw dashboards in Splunk.

I got splunk output k8s container's stdout in the following message. The `kubernetes` and `log_processed` fields are converted to json (I think it's done by AWS cloudwatch?).
But the actual log message printed by my program (in this case it's a customized k8s controller) is not converted to json.

Could someone help explain why and how should I debug and fix this? I really appreciate it!

```
{
   kubernetes: { [+] 
   } 
   log: {"level":"debug","ts":16,"msg":"Attempt to clean up old log","logDir":"/var/log/foo"}

   log_processed: { [+] 
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have JSON embedded in JSON - Splunk doesn't 'know' that nested JSON should be another JSON: it views it as the *contents* of the higher-level JSON item.

The way to handle this is either:

- don't encapsulate JSON inside JSON
- use inline [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex) statements or `props.conf`/`transforms.conf` to handle field extractions